# Is it possible to create an AI program that successfully replicates a simple organism like a bacteria?

Tags: java, artificial-intelligence

After some research, it seems like I would have to start by programming an atom, then use that to create elements, and then the organism. Is this even possible? I am fairly new to the whole programming thing so I am not entirely aware of its capabilities. I can really use some help. Thanks in advance! (Btw the programming language I'm going to use is Java)

Comment: That would be insanely slow; even bacteria have enormous numbers of atoms.  Also, you'll need electrons, nucleons, and perhaps quarks.  Finally, that's physics, not AI.

Comment: If you want to create a new kind of AI, first you need to define I; then you can work out a plan to make an A one. Note, however, that it's a rich and mature field -- don't waste your time mucking around without reading up first, *a lot.*

Comment: You're making this too easy. Try creating all this with a basic Turing machine. Then try to have it quickly evolve to a being capable of mentation such as Rush Limbaugh (no maybe the bacterium is a better example). Now you're talkin' some fun!

Comment: The question is: do you know enough about atomic physics to be able to replicate such a thing?  Does anyone yet?

Comment: I would suggest start with a big bang ;)

Comment: "If you wish to make an apple pie from scratch, you must first invent the universe." -- Carl Sagan. Which is perhaps why most AI researchers do a bit of abstraction.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can probably simulate basic bacteria-like behaviors such as reproduction or genetic evolution at a macroscopic level.

However I do not believe that it is possible to simulate entire cells at an atomic level with the knowledge and the computing power that is currently available. Currently we need massive computer clusters - or even world-wide computing grids - just to simulate the folding of a single protein molecule. I think simulating an entire cell *in operation* is still a bit beyond us.

That said, anything is *possible* (as in *not impossible*) - and if you manage it you will probably have more than 15 minutes of fame ;-)

Answer (score 5):

It turns out you don't need to programmatically recreate chemistry or physics to get interesting behavior out of your simulated organisms.  [Cellular automata](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cellular_automata) is the name of a branch of computer science that focuses on the emergent behavior of lots of little dumb machines (organisms.)

[Conway's Game of Life](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conway%27s_Game_of_Life) is the classic visual example.  More serious ones tend into cater to some kind of heuristic search problem (see [genetic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genetic_algorithm) and [memetic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memetic_algorithm) algorithms, or [swarm intellegence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swarm_intelligence).)

Answer (score 3):

1. This has nothing to do with artificial intelligence.

   To simulate a bacterium from the atoms up you would need one hell of a computer. Just try calculating how many atoms there are in a bacterium, and how long it would take to simulate all of the atomic interactions that take place over the course of, say, a microsecond.

   Writing a simulation involves decisions about *granularity*. You can represent a whole nation with three or four numbers in a high-level strategic game, or down to the level of individual citizens (each represented by three or four numbers) in a demographics/epidemiology simulation.

   We don't know all there is to know about how things are arranged in a bacterium. A crudely sketched simulation of one might just die (although that would be a very interesting result).

If you are new to programming, this is the wrong place to start-- you'll just wind up very frustrated. Start with basic programming exercises, work up to a crude simulation of bacteria in a dish (increment the population number every five minutes of sim time, learn about Fibonacci numbers), then try a sim of bacterial evolution -- with genes/proteins abstracted at a level much higher than nucleotides and amino acids. That will be enough to keep you happily occupied for a year or so, and then you can look at protein folding, ecology, bioinformatics, epigenetics, whatever takes your interest.

Answer (score 0):

The smug answer is "anything is possible".  A more realistic answer is that it all depends on how much time you're willing to invest, how smart you are, how well you understand the basic principles of life, and how realistic you want your simulation to be.

I also wonder if scientific understanding is even now to the point where we 100% understand even a simple organism well enough to 100% simulate it.

You might want to start someplace more abstract - there are lots of different Alife (artificial life) models out there that you could start with, and then work towards greater complexity and realism as you get more familiar with programming and the subject matter.

As a starting place, I've always had a soft spot for John Holland's "ECHO" model:  http://tuvalu.santafe.edu/projects/echo/echo.html

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible? Technically yes. I think really what you're asking about are things like [bioinformatics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bioinformatics) or [genetic algorithms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genetic_algorithm). Though to put it simply it's going to be way over your head for a while if you're new to programming and usually requires deep understanding of both fields you're trying to merge. I've personally always found [nasa's implementation](http://scienceblogs.com/goodmath/2008/11/evolution_produces_better_ante.php) to be really interesting, but hopefully at the least this will give you something to research.

Answer (score 0):

You should start at a higher level than atoms, in a simple cell there are billions of atoms, each atom is tied together in chemical substances, whose properties are totally different from atoms.

Despite we start to understand how to read a DNA, we don't know a lot about it. The only feasible way, is to simulate at bacteria level.